# Measuring isolated AC signals with a single ADC that has common ground inputs

Tags: adc, transformer

In my setup I have a power transformer (XFMR6) and some load connected to it.

Need to build a device that takes samples of U, I at the input and output of the transformer.

The measuring networks have to be halvanically isolated from the current networks. I plan to use ACS712 for the current sensors and I have no problems with it.

To make voltage measurements I plan to use small transformers (XFMR3 and XFMR4) connected to ADC that has only single ended inputs with a common ground. Will there be problems if the two signals come in different phases? What if there will be no grounding?

[image: This is not the actual schematic, but it shows what do I want]

Comment: Seems good to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To make voltage measurements I plan to use small transformers (XFMR3
>   and XFMR4) connected to ADC that has only single ended inputs with a
>   common ground.

It's probably a good idea to use transformers to isolate what might be dangerous voltages. Make sure they are types that are safe to use i.e. are effectively double insulated or have an earthed screen.

You will need to bias the AC output to the mid-point of your ADC's input voltage range and take care to ensure you don't put excessive voltages on the ADC pins. This is usually achieved using components as simple as resistors.

> Will there be problems if the two signals come in
>   different phases?

If you are only making voltage measurements then the phase doesn't matter but, if you plan to try and calculate power (by multiplying the output with the current sensor output) then phase is very important and needs to be correct.

> What if there will be no grounding?

The secondary sides need to be connected to a common point on your ADC and, as said earlier, if the correct transformers are used, no grounding is necessary.